# Basic Authentication not enabling on Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am working on a REST WebService. Now as per the requirement, I need to make the webservice secure. To do that I tired to use Spring Security in my application by enabling basic authentication. But Still i can access the app without authentication. I am using only annotations to do all the configuration. Please help me

UPDATE1: I am Deploying it on JBOSS EAP 6.4

Here is the WebSecurityConfig.java which enables the security

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${ldap.url}")
    private String ldapUrl;

    @Value("${ldap.userDN}")
    private String ldapuserDN;


    @Value("${ldap.password}")
    private String ldapPassword;


    @Override
    @Order(1)
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        //.and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    @Order(2)
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        LdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuth());
        return provider;
    }
    @Bean
    public BindAuthenticator bindAuth(){
        BindAuthenticator bindAuther=new BindAuthenticator(ldapContext());
        String [] patternList=new String[1];
        patternList[0]="cn={0},ou=ColtUsers,dc=eu,dc=colt";
        bindAuther.setUserDnPatterns(patternList);
        return bindAuther;
    }
    @Bean
    public  DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource ldapContext(){
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource context= new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://host:390");
        context.setUserDn("dndeatils");
        context.setPassword("password");
        return context;
    }
}
```

here is the appconfig.java

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("package") 
@EnableWebMvc

public class AppConfig {  
}
```

Here is the WebAppInitializer

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
        ctx.register(WebSecurityConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        dynamic.addMapping("/*");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `DelegatingFilterProxy` in your `WebAppInitializer`

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
        ctx.register(WebSecurityConfig.class);

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    

        // This ContextLoaderListener 
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        // This Filter 
        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        dynamic.addMapping("/*");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
   }  
}
```

Comment: I got an exception after this

 No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegaingFilterProxy.java:252) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.ava:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]